# read last comment from redmine

Tags: python, python-3.x, redmine

I have a code which connects to redmine, download an excel file, parse commands to execute on remote server. In total there are 13 commands to execute. Before executing next command, I have to get customer's confirmation by "ok" sign. I want that script listens last comment on redmine and execute the command if customer write "ok".

For now, I am able to do that if I give myself the input. I.E here is the code:

---

```
import sys
import requests
from redminelib import Redmine
from dts_viraj_EC40 import get_attachment
from dts_viraj_EC40 import format_file
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

get_attachment.get_excel()

format_file.parse_excel_sheet()
format_file.file_crop()
format_file.delete_lines()

url = 'http://xxxxxx/issues/4'


count=0

while True:
     # open with GET method
     resp = requests.get(url)
     html_content = resp.text
     soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
     y = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "wiki"})
     result = y[-1].text
     # print(y[-1].text)
     operation=input(result)





     if operation == "ok" or operation == "OK":
        with open("/home/mufit/dts_com") as execute:
          l = execute.readlines()
          print(l[count])

     count += 1

     if count == 13:
        print("script done")
        break
```

This code, prints last comment from redmine and ask me a user input from terminal. If I type "ok" or "OK" prints the command to execute. Like in this example:

```
okok
/custom/app/viraj-batch-database/bin/EC40.sh /custom/data/mustt/mission_22032019/EC40_T_6257294_PPCLI.PLU92F10

okok
/custom/app/viraj-batch-database/bin/EC40.sh /custom/data/mustt/mission_22032019/EC40_T_6298362_PPCLI.PLU92F10
```

The first "ok" is last redmine comment and second one is what I've typed on the terminal then gives me the appropriate command.

I want, the script take this input automatically from redmine; each time that customer put "ok" comment in redmine, script will print the appropriate command otherwise will give an error message and quit the program.

[how script works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU572.png)

[redmine last comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBJKW.png)

Comment: I do not understand why I recieved "-1" vote, I just asked a question...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, so I can't speak for whoever did, but if I had to guess it might be that this question doesn't really have a [mcve] and isn't terribly clear. For example, "that script this input automatically from redmine" is hard to parse.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback John Coleman, I edited my post. On the other hand, I know it's complicated to explain what I want to do (at least for me). If somebody needs more detail, I will be glad to give more information or share other modules.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code may solve your problem, it's from redmine's website.

```
GET /issues/[id].xml?include=journals
GET /issues/[id].json?include=journals
```

[wiki from redmine](https://redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_IssueJournals)

[python-redmine Documentation](https://python-redmine.com/resources/issue.html?highlight=journals#journals)